# Web api model binding doesn't bind the list

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

Developing a web api and angularjs application, I'm trying to post a list of SomethingModel to save on serverside, here is the action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public void SendMessage(List<SomethingModel> model)
{
    //model is null here
}
```

There is the array in the request body but the model does not bind if I add ModelBinding attribute as in :

```
public void SendMessage([ModelBinder]List<SomethingModel> model)
```

I got an empty list, so the question is how should I make web api bind a list of complex objects?

Here is the angularjs controller

```
myControllers.controller('messageCtrl', ['$scope','somethings', 'Message',
function ($scope, somethings, Message) {
    $scope.somethings = somethings;
    var message = new Message($scope.somethings);
    $scope.save = function () {
        message.$save().then( function () {
            $scope.go('/somewhere);
        });
    }
}
]);
```

and the view:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
       <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="sth in somethings">
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="opt00" name="selected" ng-model="sth.Selected"/></td>
            <td class="sorting_1">{{sth.Name}}</td>
            <td class=" ">{{sth.Title}}</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If I change Massage service instantiation to

```
var message = new Message(new Array($scope.somethings));
```

Then this would be the json object that I get:

```
{
  "0": [
    {
      "Selected": false,
      "Name": "رضا",
      "Title": "دوستانی"
    },
    {
      "Selected": true,
      "Name": "name2",
      "Title": "title2"
    }
 ]
}
```

**Update:**

The message service:

```
myServices.factory('Message', ['$resource',
function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/ManualMessage/SendMessage', null);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
[HttpPost]
public void SendMessage([FromBody] List<SomethingModel> model)
{
    //model is null here
}
```